# is there any way to import NULLS to mySQL inside of single quotes?

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I'm using VBA that encloses every field with single quotes in order to import into mySQL and noticed that every variation I tried on NULL for numeric data types imported as 0.  If I drop the backticks the nulls import fine, so I think my question boils down to this: if there any way to indicate NULL data **inside of** single quotes in a mySQL import?

this [website](http://staraphd.blogspot.com/2009/09/import-null-values-into-mysql-via.html) shows a bunch of examples, but nothing inside of single quotes.

thanks!

Comment: Backticks? Could you provide some example SQL, because backticks are normally reserved for table/column names. Trying to insert a *value* delimited by backticks should throw an error.

Comment: I guess single quotes then?  I'll post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string inside the single quotes is escaped, too, then there is no way of making it *NULL*. That would negate the purpose of quotes+escaping.

If it is not escaped, you could "break out" of the single quotes with a single quote. For example if you store the string `'/0+'` it will become `''/0+''` (say: empty string divided by zero plus empty string) which is *NULL* because anything divided by zero is *NULL*.